# Deleting record in Kafka StateStore does not work (NullPointerException thrown on .delete(key))

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a materialized in-memory statestore in my code. I have another separate stream that is supposed to look up and delete records based on some criteria.

I need to allow my stream to access and delete records in the previously built statestore.
I have the following code below

```
@bean
public StreamBuilder myStreamCodeBean(StreamBuilder streamBuilder) {
    //create store supplier
    KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier myStoreSupplier = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("MyStateStore");

    //materialize statstore and enable caching
    Materialized materializedStore = Materialized.<String, MyObject>as(myStoreSupplier)
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
            .withValueSerde(myObjectSerde)
            .withCachingEnabled();

    //other code here that creates KTable, and another stream to consume records into ktable from another topic
    //........

    //another stream that consumes another topic and deletes records in store with some logic
    streamsBuilder
        .stream("someTopicName", someConsumerObject)
        .filter((key, value) -> {
            KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]> kvStore = myStoreSupplier.get();
            kvStore.delete(key);  //StateStore never "open" and this throws nullpointerexception (even tho key is NOT null)
            return true;
        }
        .to("some topic name here", producerObject);
    return streamBuilder;
}
```

The error that is thrown is really generic. The error is that Kafka streams is not running.

Doing some debugging, I found that my statestore isn't "open" when doing delete.

What am I doing wrong here? I can read records using ReadOnlyKeyValueStore but I need to delete so I can't use that.

any help appreciated.

Comment: When, in your code, do you use `materializedStore` ? Can you show the full code ?

Comment: You cannot access a store in `filter` -- you need to use `transform()` (or similar) and add the store to `transform()`.

Comment: @Yannick I use materializedStore variable for materializing my ktable.

Comment: @matthias I will try to use transform(), didn't know you cant access it in filter

Comment: As the JavaDocs of `filter` explain: `This is a stateless record-by-record operation.` :)

Answer (score 2):

State store must be accessed through the processor's context and not using the supplier object.

After creating the store, you need to ensure that it is accessible by the processor in which you are trying to access the store from.

---

If your store is a local store, then you need to specify which processors are going to access the store.

If your store is a global store, then it is accessible by all the processors in the topology.

---

You are creating a stream using `streamsBuilder.stream()` and *at least from the code you have posted*, you doesn't seem to give your processor access to the state store.

1. Ensure that you have called [addStateStore()](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#addStateStore-org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StoreBuilder-) in `StreamsBuilder`
2. To get the state store in the processor, we need to use `context.getStateStore(storeName)`.
   You can refer the following [example](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/a8a668b9f885bb130a2eef1f7bc487e555c71f2d/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/EventDeduplicationLambdaIntegrationTest.java)
3. (I don't *think* we can access state store in `filter()` because it is a stateless operation). So, you can use [Processor](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process-org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorSupplier-java.lang.String...-) or [Transformer](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#transform-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.TransformerSupplier-java.lang.String...-) for and pass in the state store names (MyStateStore in your case).

Comment: Thanks for the examples. I do not have ProcessorContext in my code anywhere, I believe we are trying to avoid it since it is on the lower level of kafka? Is there anyway to get StateStore without ProcessorContext? Something similar to how we can get ReadOnlyKeyValueStore (using getKafkaStream().store("storename", QueryableStoreTypes.KeyValueStore())

Comment: @ZunairSyed `ReadOnlyKeyValueStore`, as the name itself says, we cannot modify it. So this is meant for reading the values in the store outside of the topology. I don't *think* we can have write-access to a state store without context object and `filter()` doesn't seem to have it.